# VB Script Application: Path Not Found for ASP Classic Page

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic

I am having issues with routing from a VB6 DLL. When my web page calls a classic ASP page called "Recreate Session" I get this error message:

```
Path not found

/Path/to/File/RecreateSession.asp, line 211
```

Line 211 is a call to this:

```
cValidate.Initialize
```

With some arguments that are a little bit too company specific for me to post.

cValidate is defined like this:

```
Set cValidate = Session("cValidate")
```

Out of our 5 machines this works on 3 of them with identical code, which makes me think it's some kind of configuration issue. I have compared the IIS setup and configurations and as far as I can tell they are completely identical. I know there is not a lot of information in this post but this is everything I have.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The title and the question indicate VB6 and ASP while the tags indicate VB.NET and ASP.NET. If the tags are wrong then please fix them. If the tags are right, please edit the question to clearly indicate how.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Sorry about that, I tried "ASP" at first and could not find the right tag. I have found it and updated it as well as included the correct tag for VB script.

Comment: Ok so the problem is it works 3 out 5 times?  So then what are the hardware and software differences between the 3 that work and the 2 that do not?  Are you using a webrowser ?  If they are the same, but its a different operating system, that and settings on the browser can be different unless controlled by a domain controller or other method.

Comment: @easleyfixed In 3 out of 5 environments. They are slightly different, basically it works on 2008 R2 servers but due to compliance issues we cannot continue running that version.

Comment: Hmm the error is "Path not found" so find out where in the script it creates that string to generate that path and work backwards.   Sometimes you need "../directory" with the ../ to go back up one directory .. and another thing to try is check your settings again, is there a virtual directory for this path OR a URL rewrite rule?

Comment: This could be  permission or path issue, you need to check the requested path. Also, you can enable FRT in IIS for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing.

Comment: @TengFeiXie  Thanks for the help, it turned out to be a path issue (which was apparent from the error message) for a COM component reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix ended up being that one of my 20 year old VB script DLLs had to be registered with the COM component registration in powershell for the application to be able to find it.

```
$comAdmin.InstallComponent("HOME",$rootdir + "\DLLs\MyDll.DLL","","")
```

Hopefully this helps anyone else who, like me, started programing within the last 10 years and has never dealt with this kind of setup.

Comment: Where did powershell come into the original question?

Comment: @user692942 The original question was about a path not found issue with a COM component, so powershell was my technology of choice to re-register that component.  would you recommend I edit the answer to use REGSVR32?

Comment: If it’s just COM registration there is a plethora of question and answers that already cover this issue.